# IIS Requests Login Credentials on Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

I have decided to transfer several of my web applications from one virtual server ot another. The way everything works on my current server is pretty bad - everyone has rights for reading and accessing the content of my "applications" folder on the machine, and so does the IIS. I want to organize stuff on the new server, so only IIS can access this folder.

I have installed IIS and the ASP.NET addons on the new server, and forced my test website to Windows Authentication, as all of my websites are configured on the current server. Then, after doing some reading regarding the permissions, I have given full control to the folder that contains my website to the next users: IIS_IUSRS & TestAppPool (which is the Application Pool I have created for my 'Test' application).

For some reason when I try to access the website from another user within the domain, through the browser, it promts for Login Credentials. I would like to understand why my application wont retrieve the permissions I have granted the IIS users upon accessing the website.

Comment: Anonymous Authentication and specifying the application pool as a "specific user" did the trick, but I do need to be able to retrieve the windows credentials of the user who is currently logged into the website (can't do it with annonymous authentication). Meaning - I need to use Windows Authentication. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this would help, but can you try changing the app pool's identity to *Network Service*?